# How to view long paths in Windows Explorer search results?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I would like to see the full paths in the windows explorer search results. Currently, it shows like this:

[image]

Note that I cannot resize the first column. There is also a menu item with "Size all columns to fit", but it is currently grayed out.

I can select other listing types, such as details, but it will not show the full path, which is usually of a much higher importance when browsing through search results.

Finally, I tried Sort by, it allows to manually set the width of columns in pixels, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

Switch to the "View" tab and change the Layout to "Details". Once that is done you are able to resize the columns to display the full information for all of your search items at once.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Fast, easy, and solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click goal file, there is an option called **Open file location** which will lead you find out the file location easily.

For your reference:

[Search option in Windows 10 file manager refuses to display paths](https://superuser.com/questions/1249782/search-option-in-windows-10-file-manager-refuses-to-display-paths)

[How do I view the full path in search results?](https://superuser.com/questions/616021/how-do-i-view-the-full-path-in-search-results)